# Android - Read data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data set like:

```
Root:
----Users:
--------UserID:
------------UserID:
------------Username:
------------Password:
```

I want to get the username of the user using the userID which is obtained from the previous activity, for which I've written a query :

```
tableDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
tableNameQuery = tableDatabaseReference.child("Username").orderByChild("UserID").equalTo(userID);
```

However this is not showing any result.

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User id is always unique so better put it inside Child and don't need to provide User child after reference.

```
tableDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
tableNameQuery = tableDatabaseReference.child(userID);
tableNameQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name1 = dataSnapshot.child("Username").getValue(String.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!
But one question, why didn't the equalTo() didn't work?

Comment: It's not problem with equal to it's problem with your database path you provided

Answer (score 0):

You can read user name by following query

```
        String userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/"+userId)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //Use your Pojo class for reading values from database
                        OtherUser user = dataSnapshot.getValue(OtherUser.class);
                        Log.i("user",user.UserName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Where OtherUser is following, replace OtherUser with your own pojo

```
    class OtherUser{
        String UserName;
        String Password;
    }
```